# Should I digitally sign all files before I build?

Tags: code-signing

I just bought a digital signing cert and will be using MS signtool to sign my vb program (made using digital studio 10). The program is pretty simple (no dll files--basically the exe and some xml, mdb files). My question is: should I sign all my files (even readme or ico files) before I build the program, and then sign the packaged install exe (the install package was made with installshield).I don't know what people do in the dev community . I read this [Which files should be digitally signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520453/which-files-should-be-digitally-signed) and the link in it, but just a bit unsure about database and other file types (html, ico, etc), and what about microsoft files like dotnet4.0 that come packaged with the application --aren;t they already signed?

Comment: `signtool` will only sign particular file types anyway (like CAB, PE files and so on).

Comment: thank you. what about MS files like dotnet4 exe? is there a protocol regarding already signed files ?

Comment: don't sign files already signed by others.